# How do I change the complete combobox in JavaFX via CSS

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

I created a window in JavaFX Scene Builder and costumized the look via CSS. It works fine but the settings for the combobox doesnt apply for the whole box.[image: Combobox Window]

How do I correct this?

Comment: You should try the following : `.combo-box-base > .arrow-button { -fx-background-color: YOUR_COLOR; }` and have a look on ComboBoxBase in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#comboboxbase).

Comment: it worked thanks ^